# Quickly Inter-Process Communication with signal about changes

Tags: c++, com, ipc, shared-memory, dbus

I know several ways for IPC, such as:

1. Shared memory
2. DBus, COM and other technologies
3. Via file

First method to share memory directly into RAM, but i can't know about change in common memory immediatly.

Second method is good, but not is a crossplatform solution.

Third method is a crossplatform and via platform api i can know about change in common memory immediatly. But read/write file time can be big.

Is exist crossplatform solution that can share memory directly into RAM and can
issue signal about change in common memory immediatly?

UPDATE 1. For example, is exist protocol and technology for file IPC that reduces cost of time via database files strucrure?

Comment: I _think_ the short answer to your question is "no". But what is it you want to communicate - how large is each "portion" of data, etc?

Comment: interprocess semaphores + shared memory are portable enough (POSIX and Windows), although not *trivially* portable.

Comment: @MatsPetersson It is a theoretical question. I'm interesting about all cases that offer different solutions.

Comment: The problem with theoretical questions is that it becomes quite hypothetical what the solution is... ;) Portability is also largely a case of "definition". As long as similar functionality is available in the target OS's, you can probably implement a compatibility layer that hides the ACTUAL implementation - so shared memory and semaphotes, pipes (named or unnamed), etc are all possible solutions.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I understand you. See my "UPDATE 1" row in question.

Comment: Not sure that makes anything clearer. Databases tend to use files to store things, but communication is done via pipes, shared memory etc.

Comment: @AntonKovalenko: it's trivially portable by [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess.html)

Comment: @AndyT Do Boost.Interprocess issue any signal about change in common memory immediatly?

Comment: @Milovidov: yes, but only if you need this

Comment: @AndyT How it do? I had read documentation about Boost.Interprocess but didn't see about it.

Comment: @Milovidov: [Boost.Interprocess: Synchronization mechanisms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one solution http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=SingleApplication

This solution have use shared memrory for data storage and have use on Windows named pipe, on Unix local domain socket for sending messges about changes immediatly.

Comment: please mark your answer as useful, in order to mark the thread as "Answered". Thank you.